Edit TinyURL link destination on a free account
On a free TinyURL account, a TinyURL that you create cannot have its destination edited. Also, if you try to delete it, you are advised that it will be hidden from view, but that it still exists:

Remove TinyURL from List
Removing a TinyURL will make the URL not show up in
your list of TinyURLs, but the TinyURL will still function.


The TinyURL can, however, be renamed. I was hoping that by renaming it, the original TinyURL would then become available to reuse with a new destination.
Was I wrong to assume this? Or, does it take a while for it to become available again? Or, is there another solution?

Unfortunately, you can't circumvent the limitations of the free account that easily. You are creating a new TinyURL when you "rename" it and both of them continue to function.
If you control the destination address you could reroute it yourself server-side.
Remember Asimov's "3 Laws of Linkbotics":
A robot may not modify a free-tier link destination.  A robot may not delete a free-tier link or, through inaction, allow the link to expire. A robot must enforce all restrictions of the free-tier plan regardless of how clever the human is except where such restrictions would conflict with a decision by the human to deliver money to the robot's owners.
TinyURL Plans > Link Management



Link Management
Free
Pro
  Bulk  
  Enterprise  




Customize URL Aliases  






Tag Links
❌





Rename Link Aliases






Edit Link Destinations
❌





Delete Links
❌





Default Link Expiration
  Never  
  Never  
90 Days
Custom


Set Link Expiration Dates
❌






